# Is every irrational number containing only $2$ distinct digits, transcendental?

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, decimal-expansion, transcendental-numbers

> If we have an irrational number, consisting of only $2$ distinct digits, for example:
>
> $$0.01011011101111011111 \cdots$$
>
> Can we conclude that the number is transcendental?

It is conjectured that every irrational algebraic number is normal in base $10$. This would imply that the answer to my question is yes. But can we prove it?

Comment: This can well be a duplicate, if so, I apologize in advance.

Comment: Killing a mosquito with a howitzer you're not even sure exists.  Welcome to mathematics, I guess.

Comment: @DanUznanski I don't really think this constitutes killing a mosquito with a dubious howitzer; rather, the OP is observing that their question can't have an easy negative answer, which is useful data for someone trying to solve it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What is a howitzer ?

Comment: @Peter [A household pest control device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howitzer).

Comment: Well not in base $2$, and it might be that base $3$ is an easier place to start, because the Cantor Set is well studied.

Comment: Metaphors aside, is there a specific algebraic number you're giving as an example? I tried a few things in Robert Munafo's RIES but couldn't find something like your number, e.g., $\sqrt{e^{-9}}$.

Comment: This problem is wide open. As far as we know, _all_ algebraic irrationals could have expansions which eventually only use two digits, in _all_ bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at [this answer in mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173414/conjecture-on-irrational-algebraic-numbers). Our conditions are not strong enough to use the theorem though, as we just have $c_x(n)\leq 2^n$.

Comment: Can you explain the complexity in this context ? When can we conclude that a number is either rational or transcendental with the complexity ? In particular, is $0.ababbabbbabbbbabbbbb\cdots$ with distinct digits $a$ and $b$ always transcendental ?

Comment: when there is a $k$ such that the number of distinct blocks of length $n$ that appear in the word is less than $kn$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Peter that one wont work. The number of blocks of length $n$ is not bounded by $kn$ for any $k$.

Comment: no, a block of length $n$ is a substring of length $n$. For example, the number $0.00000000$ has only one block of every length.

Comment: So, the distinct blocks of length $3$ in my example would be $bbb,abb,bab,bba,aba$ ?

Comment: If the number of consecutive $a$'s and that of consecutive $b$'s are both limited, can we then apply the theorem ?

Comment: no, we wan't apply it even then, it seems to be pretty limited really. There is also a theorem about the number of digit-changes. see here: https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1560